# Obtaining a reference to the object a variable is a member of

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

I have a customer class:

```
Public Class Customer
   Public Name As String
End Class
```

And I pass the name to a subroutine, foo:

```
Dim myCustomer as New Customer
myCustomer.Name = "Bill"
Foo(myCustomer.Name)
```

Using Reflection, is there any way for Foo to obtain a reference to the MyCustomer *instance* that the name parameter is a member of?

```
Public Sub Foo (name As String)
   'Any way to obtain a reference to the MyCustomer instance from
   'the name parameter alone?
End Sub
```

Comment: No, at that point, it is a plain old string that could have come from anywhere.

Comment: You could simply pass the object instance itself and change the foo parameter to `Object` but if you're passing strings from different classes with different properties, you would need to write code to find out which class is being passed etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.

Think of how these objects look in memory. Put simply, it'll look something like this:

```
| Address | Value                 |
|---------|-----------------------|
| 0x01    | "Bill"                |
| 0x02    | Customer(Name = 0x01) |
```

When you make a call to the method, you're passing in the address to the string.

```
Foo(myCustomer.Name)
```

...is equivalent to...

```
String n = myCustomer.Name; // n is now 0x01

Foo(n);
```

Once in `Foo`, all you can see is 0x01. It has no link to 0x02, where the customer instance is stored. You'd have to basically brute-force the memory to find references to 0x01, which isn't going to be possible (or at least, good practice) in a high-level, memory-managed language like VB.

The only option is to introduce a new overload that takes type `Customer`, and perhaps calls `Foo(String)` for the non-customer-specific bits.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping that with all the other tricks in the .NET toolbox (e.g. NameOf, ParameterInfo, etc.) there would be a way to do it.